# How to retrieve property file name in jsp?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tomcat, spring-properties

I want to get the name of the property file being loaded at the spring initialization (during tomcat container startup) in the JSP during runtime.

```
<util:properties id="propertyConfigurer" location="classpath:${devTarget_propertyFileClassPathHere}"/>
<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="propertyConfigurer" />
```

Where **devTarget** is being provided by Tomcat's catalina.properties file.
And based on this value, a particular property file gets loaded during spring init.

Now I want to read this **devTarget** in JSP to render something based upon the environment, where devTarget tells the environment.

How should I do this? So that devTarget can be easily accessible in JSP.

Something like:

```
<spring:eval expression="@propertyConfigurer.getProperty('propertyNameHere')" />
```

Comment: Done this by storing the values in context-param of web.xml and then used that in jsp using jstl.

Answer (score 0):

Done this by storing the values in context-param of web.xml and then used that in jsp using jstl.